# Making a map with excel data in R: How to convert north and east coordinate format to decimal degrees?

Tags: excel, mapping, coordinate-systems, ggspatial

I am trying to make a map in R. The data gives me east coordinates in the column east_coord with the format: -18445. And the north coordinates in the column north_coord with the format: 6914633. They are already numeric. I am new to mapping in R. I don't know what coordinate reference system this is, but I know that I want it to be in decimal degrees. Please help! Thank you, this is my first time using stack overflow.

I tried the parzer package:

library(parzer)
parse_lat(6914633)

Then I get this warning message:
Warning: not within -90/90 range, got: 6884305
check that you did not invert lon and lat[1] NaN

Which leads me to think that the data just needs decimal places, and then it's in decimal degrees? I'm confused because I don't know what the current format is.

Also, how would I add decimal places if that is the case?

I also tried this:

library(rgdal)

df <- spTransform(df, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))